# Cut/Copy/Paste in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt

I want to implement cut, copy and paste operation in QGraphicsView in Qt. I have my all items stored in one class. What I want is when I draw one item and then I can cut or copy that item and paste it at some other location I want to paste. Can anyone please suggest me with the method to procced the same.

cadgraphicsscene.cpp

```
#include<QtWidgets>
#include "cadgraphicsscene.h"
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QDebug>
CadGraphicsScene::CadGraphicsScene(QObject *parent, QUndoStack *undoStack)
    : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    setFlags();
    mUndoStack = undoStack;
    textItem = 0;
    myTextColor = Qt::black;
    // connect selectionChanged signal to selectItems slot
    connect(this, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(selectItems()));
}
void CadGraphicsScene::setFlags()
{
    // set/unset all the flags
    mFirstClick = true;
    mSecondClick = false;
    mThirdClick = false;
    mPaintFlag = false;
}
void CadGraphicsScene::setMode(Mode mode)
{
    // determine the mode set
    entityMode = mode;
    if (entityMode == NoMode)
        areItemsSelectable(true);
    else
        areItemsSelectable(false);
}
void CadGraphicsScene::editorLostFocus(mText *item)
{
    QTextCursor cursor = item->textCursor();
    cursor.clearSelection();
    item->setTextCursor(cursor);
    if (item->toPlainText().isEmpty()) {
        removeItem(item);
        item->deleteLater();
    }
}
void CadGraphicsScene::areItemsSelectable(bool b)
{
    // make items selectable
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, itemList)
    {
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, b);
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, b);
    }
}
void CadGraphicsScene::deleteItems()
{
    // delete selected items
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, itemList)
    {
        if (item->isSelected())
        {
            mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandDelete(this, item));
            item->setSelected(false);
        }
    }
}
void CadGraphicsScene::selectItems()
{
    // refresh record of selected items and their starting positions
    selectedItems.clear();
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, itemList)
    {
        if (item->isSelected())
        {
            if (dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem *>(item))
            {
                selectedItems.append(qMakePair(
                                         dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem *>(item),
                                         item->scenePos()));
            }
        }
    }
}
void CadGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    // mousePressEvent in the graphicsScene
    static int id = 0;
    switch (entityMode)
    {
    case NoMode:
        qDebug() << "No Mode";
        break;
    case PointMode:
        pointItem = new Point(++id);
        pointItem->setPos(mouseEvent->scenePos());
        itemList.append(pointItem);
        mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandAdd(this, pointItem));
        break;
    case LineMode:
        if (mFirstClick)
        {
            start_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
            mFirstClick = false;
            mSecondClick = true;
        }
        else if (!mFirstClick && mSecondClick)
        {
            end_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
            mPaintFlag = true;
            mSecondClick = false;
        }
        if (mPaintFlag)
        {
            lineItem = new Line(++id, start_p, end_p);
            lineItem->setLine(start_p.x(), start_p.y(), end_p.x(), end_p.y());
            itemList.append(lineItem);
            mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandAdd(this, lineItem));
            setFlags();
        }
        break;
    case CircleMode:
        if (mFirstClick)
        {
            start_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
            mFirstClick = false;
            mSecondClick = true;
        }
        else if (!mFirstClick && mSecondClick)
        {
            end_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
            mPaintFlag = true;
            mSecondClick = false;
        }
        if (mPaintFlag)
        {
            circleItem = new Circle(++id, start_p, end_p);
            itemList.append(circleItem);
            mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandAdd(this, circleItem));
            setFlags();
        }
        break;
    case EllipseMode:
        if (mFirstClick)
        {
            start_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
            mFirstClick = false;
            mSecondClick = true;
        }
        else if (!mFirstClick && mSecondClick)
        {
            mid_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
            mFirstClick = false;
            mSecondClick = false;
            mThirdClick = true;
        }
        else if (!mSecondClick && mThirdClick)
        {
            end_p = mouseEvent->scenePos();
            mThirdClick = false;
            mPaintFlag = true;
        }
        if (mPaintFlag)
        {
            ellipseItem = new Ellipse(++id, start_p, mid_p, end_p);
            itemList.append(ellipseItem);
            mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandAdd(this, ellipseItem));
            setFlags();
        }
        break;
    case TextMode:
        textItem = new mText(++id);
        textItem->setFont(myFont);
        itemList.append(textItem);
        mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandAdd(this, textItem));
        textItem->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
        textItem->setZValue(1000.0);
        connect(textItem, SIGNAL(lostFocus(mText*)),
                this, SLOT(editorLostFocus(mText*)));
        connect(textItem, SIGNAL(selectedChange(QGraphicsItem*)),
                this, SIGNAL(itemSelected(QGraphicsItem*)));
        addItem(textItem);
        textItem->setDefaultTextColor(myTextColor);
        textItem->setPos(mouseEvent->scenePos());
        emit textInserted(textItem);
        setFlags();
    default:
        ;
    }
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
}
void CadGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    // if any items moved, then create undo commands
    foreach (itemPos item, selectedItems)
    {
        if (item.first->scenePos() != item.second)
        {
            mUndoStack->push(new CadCommandMove(item.first, item.second.x(),
                                                item.second.y(), item.first->x(),
                                                item.first->y()));
        }
    }
    // refresh record of selected items and call base mouseReleaseEvent
    selectItems();
    QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
}
void CadGraphicsScene::writeStream(QXmlStreamWriter *stream)
{
    // write entities in a file
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, itemList)
    {
        if (items().contains(item))
        {
            if (item->type() == Point::Type)
            {
                Point *myItem = dynamic_cast<Point *>(item);
                stream->writeStartElement("Point");
                stream->writeAttribute("id", QString::number(myItem->id));
                stream->writeAttribute("x", QString::number(myItem->x()));
                stream->writeAttribute("y", QString::number(myItem->y()));
                stream->writeEndElement();  //end of Point Item
            }
            else if (item->type() == Line::Type)
            {
                Line *myItem = dynamic_cast<Line *>(item);
                stream->writeStartElement("Line");
                stream->writeAttribute("id", QString::number(myItem->id));
                stream->writeAttribute("x1", QString::number(myItem->start_p.x()));
                stream->writeAttribute("y1", QString::number(myItem->start_p.y()));
                stream->writeAttribute("x2", QString::number(myItem->end_p.x()));
                stream->writeAttribute("y2", QString::number(myItem->end_p.y()));
                stream->writeEndElement();  //end of Line Item
            }
            else if (item->type() == Circle::Type)
            {
                Circle *myItem = dynamic_cast<Circle *>(item);
                stream->writeStartElement("Circle");
                stream->writeAttribute("id", QString::number(myItem->id));
                stream->writeAttribute("cx", QString::number(myItem->center_p.x()));
                stream->writeAttribute("cy", QString::number(myItem->center_p.y()));
                stream->writeAttribute("radius", QString::number(myItem->radius));
                stream->writeEndElement();  //end of Circle Item
            }
            else if (item->type() == Ellipse::Type)
            {
                Ellipse *myItem = dynamic_cast<Ellipse *>(item);
                stream->writeStartElement("Ellipse");
                stream->writeAttribute("id", QString::number(myItem->id));
                stream->writeAttribute("cx", QString::number(myItem->p1.x()));
                stream->writeAttribute("cy", QString::number(myItem->p1.y()));
                stream->writeAttribute("majR", QString::number(myItem->majRadius));
                stream->writeAttribute("minR", QString::number(myItem->minRadius));
                stream->writeEndElement();  //end of Ellipse Item
            }
            else if (item->type() == mText::Type)
            {
                mText *myItem = dynamic_cast<mText *>(item);
                stream->writeStartElement("MText");
                stream->writeAttribute("id", QString::number(myItem->id));
                stream->writeAttribute("x1", QString::number(myItem->x()));
                stream->writeAttribute("y1", QString::number(myItem->y()));
                stream->writeEndElement();  //end of Text Item
            }
        }
    }
}
void CadGraphicsScene::readStream(QXmlStreamReader *stream)
{
    while (!stream->atEnd())
    {
        stream->readNext();
        if (stream->isStartElement() && stream->name() == "Point")
        {
            qreal x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
            foreach (QXmlStreamAttribute attribute, stream->attributes())
            {
                if (attribute.name() == "xCoord")
                    x = attribute.value().toString().toDouble();
                if (attribute.name() == "yCoord")
                    y = attribute.value().toString().toDouble();
            }
            //            Point *myPoint = new Point;
            //            addItem(myPoint);
            //            myPoint->setPos(x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QShortcut>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle(tr("eCAD"));
    setCentralWidget(mdiArea);
    Ui_MainWindow::statusBar->showMessage("Welcome to eCAD");

//    connect(pointButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
//            this, SLOT(drawPoint()));
//    connect(lineButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
//            this, SLOT(drawLine()));
//    connect(circleButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
//            this, SLOT(drawCircle()));
//    connect(ellipseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
//            this, SLOT(drawEllipse()));

    connect(actionPoints, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(drawPoint()));
    connect(actionLine, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(drawLine()));
    connect(actionCircle, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(drawCircle()));
    connect(actionEllipse, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(drawEllipse()));
    connect(actionMText, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this,SLOT(drawText()));

    connect(actionNew, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(newFile()));
    connect(actionQuit, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(actionPrint, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(filePrint()));
    connect(actionPrintPreview, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(filePrintPreview()));
    connect(actionZoom_In, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(on_actionZoom_In_triggered()));
    connect(actionZoom_Out, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(on_actionZoom_Out_triggered()));
    connect(actionInsert_Image,SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(on_actionInsert_Image_triggered()));

    // toggle actions to false
    toggleActions(0);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::toggleActions(bool b)
{
    actionSave->setEnabled(b);
    actionPrint->setEnabled(b);
    actionPrintPreview->setEnabled(b);
    actionZoom_In->setEnabled(b);
    actionZoom_Out->setEnabled(b);
    actionPoints->setEnabled(b);
    actionLine->setEnabled(b);
    actionCircle->setEnabled(b);
    actionEllipse->setEnabled(b);
    actionMText->setEnabled(b);
    actionInsert_Image->setEnabled(b);
}

void MainWindow::setActions()
{
    // shortcut keys
    new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Escape),
                  this, SLOT(setNoMode()));
    new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_U),
                  this, SLOT(showUndoStack()));
    new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Delete),
                  this, SLOT(deleteItems()));

    QAction *actionUndo = view->undoStack->createUndoAction(this);
    QAction *actionRedo = view->undoStack->createRedoAction(this);
    actionUndo->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Undo);
    actionRedo->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Redo);
    menuEdit->addAction(actionUndo);
    menuEdit->addAction(actionRedo);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove)
    {
        QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent =
                static_cast<QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *>(event);
        QString showMessage = QString("Mouse move (%1,%2)").
                arg(mouseEvent->scenePos().x()).
                arg(mouseEvent->scenePos().y());
        Ui_MainWindow::statusBar->showMessage(showMessage);
    }
}

void MainWindow::newFile()
{
    // creates a new file
    createMdiView();
    view->newFile();
    view->scene->installEventFilter(this);
    view->show();
    setActions();

    // toggle actions to true
    toggleActions(1);
}

void MainWindow::filePrintPreview()
{
    // display print preview dialog
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QPrintPreviewDialog preview(&printer, this);
    connect(&preview, SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter *)), SLOT(print(QPrinter *)));
    preview.exec();
}

void MainWindow::filePrint()
{
    // display print dialog and if accepted print
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
        print(&printer);
}

void MainWindow::print(QPrinter *printer)
{
    // print the page
    QPainter painter(printer);
    int w = printer->pageRect().width();
    int h = printer->pageRect().height();
    QRect page(0, 0, w, h);

    QFont font = painter.font();
    font.setPixelSize((w+h)/100);
    painter.setFont(font);

    painter.drawText(page, Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight,
                     QDateTime::currentDateTime().
                     toString(Qt::DefaultLocaleShortDate));

    page.adjust(w/20, h/20, -w/20, -h/20);
    view->scene->render(&painter, page);
}

CadGraphicsView *MainWindow::createMdiView()
{
    // creates a graphicsView and add it to the MDI window
    view = new CadGraphicsView;
    mdiArea->addSubWindow(view);
    return view;
}

void MainWindow::showUndoStack()
{
    // calls an undo stack function of graphicsView
    view->showUndoStack();
}

void MainWindow::drawPoint()
{
    // calls the drawPoint function of graphicsView
    view->drawPoint();
}

void MainWindow::setNoMode()
{
    // calls the setNoMode function of graphicsView
    view->setNoMode();
}

void MainWindow::drawLine()
{
    // calls the drawLine function of graphicsView
    view->drawLine();
}

void MainWindow::drawCircle()
{
    // calls the drawCircle function of graphicsView
    view->drawCircle();
}

void MainWindow::drawEllipse()
{
    // calls the drawEllipse function of graphicsView
    view->drawEllipse();
}

void MainWindow::drawText()
{
    // calls the drawEllipse function of graphicsView
    view->drawText();
}

void MainWindow::deleteItems()
{
    // calls the deleteItems function of graphicsScene
    view->scene->deleteItems();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    // open file dialog box
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                  tr("Open File"),
                                                  QString(),
                                                  tr("file Name(*.xml)"));
    QMainWindow::statusBar()->showMessage("File opened successfully");
    if (!filename.isEmpty())
    {
        QFile file(filename);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Could not open file"));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            QXmlStreamReader  stream(&file);
            CadGraphicsScene *newScene = new CadGraphicsScene(this,
                                                              view->undoStack);
            while (!stream.atEnd())
            {
                stream.readNext();
                if (stream.isStartElement())
                {
                    if (stream.name() == "SceneData")
                        newScene->readStream(&stream);
                    else
                        stream.raiseError(QString("Unrecognised element '%1'").
                                          arg(stream.name().toString()));
                }
            }

            // check if error occured
            if (stream.hasError())
            {
                file.close();
                QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error",
                                     QString("Failed to load '%1' (%2)").
                                     arg(filename).arg(stream.errorString()));
                delete newScene;
                return;
            }

            /* close file, display new scene, delete old scene
            and display useful message */
            file.close();

            view->setScene( newScene );
            delete view->scene;
            view->scene = newScene;
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Done",
                                 QString("Loaded '%1'").arg(filename));
            return;
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
    // save file dialog box
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                  tr("Save File"),
                                                  QString(),
                                                  tr("file Name(*.xml)"));
    if(!filename.isEmpty())
    {
        QFile file(filename);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Could not open file"));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
            xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
            xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
            xmlWriter.writeStartElement("SceneData");
            xmlWriter.writeAttribute("version", "v1.0");
            xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Entities");

            view->scene->writeStream(&xmlWriter);

            xmlWriter.writeEndElement();   //end of Entities
            xmlWriter.writeEndElement();   //end of SceneData
            xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Saved",
                                 QString("Saved Scene Data to '%1'").
                                 arg(filename));
            file.close();
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionZoom_In_triggered()
{
    // Zoom in
    //graphicsView->scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionZoom_Out_triggered()
{
    // Zoom out
    //graphicsView->scale(1.0 / scaleFactor, 1.0 / scaleFactor);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionInsert_Image_triggered()
{
    // insert image dialog
    QString imagePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("open File"),"",
                                                    tr("JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;PNG(*.png)"));
    imageObject = new QImage();
    imageObject->load(imagePath);
    image = QPixmap::fromImage(*imageObject);
    //scene =new CadGraphicsScene(this);
    //scene->addPixmap(image);
    //scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
    //graphicsView->setScene(scene);
}
```

---

Using the following answer I am to have a context menu working properly, along with the cut operation working too. But my copy and paste operations are not working. I have the different classes for the different entities such as point, ellipse etc. I am adding one of my entity class, Do suggest me how to proceed further/

circle.h

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

#include "qmath.h"

class Circle : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Circle(int, QPointF, QPointF);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter,
                       const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                       QWidget *widget);
    enum { Type = UserType + 3 };
    int type() const;
    int id;

    QPointF center_p, end_p, move_p;
    qreal radius;

private:
    QVector<QPointF> stuff;
};



#endif // CIRCLE_H
```

circle.cpp

```
#include "circle.h"

Circle::Circle(int i, QPointF p1, QPointF p2)
{
    // assigns id
    id = i;

    /* set values of center point, end point
    and calculate radius of circle */
    center_p = p1;
    end_p = p2;
    radius = qSqrt(qPow((end_p.x()-center_p.x()), 2)
                   + qPow((end_p.y()-center_p.y()), 2));
}

int Circle::type() const
{
    // Enable the use of qgraphicsitem_cast with circle item.
    return Type;
}

QRectF Circle::boundingRect() const
{
    // bounding rectangle for circle
    return QRectF((center_p.x()-radius), (center_p.y()-radius),
                  (2*radius), (2*radius));
}

void Circle::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                   QWidget *widget)
{
    // draws/paints the path of circle
    QPen paintpen(Qt::black);
    paintpen.setWidth(1);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    if (isSelected())
    {
        // sets brush for center point
        painter->setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
        paintpen.setColor(Qt::red);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawEllipse(center_p, 2, 2);

        // sets pen for circumference
        paintpen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);
        paintpen.setColor(Qt::black);
        painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawEllipse(center_p, radius, radius);
    }
    else
    {
        painter->setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
        paintpen.setColor(Qt::black);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawEllipse(center_p, 2, 2);
        painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
        painter->drawEllipse(center_p, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

cadgraphicsscene.cpp

```
void CadGraphicsScene::contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent* evt)
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> itemList = items(evt->scenePos());

    QGraphicsItem* item = itemList.isEmpty() ? 0x00 : itemList.first();

    static QGraphicsItem* storedItem = 0x00;

    QMenu menu;

    //Item found
    if(item)
    {
        menu.addAction("Copy");
        menu.addAction("Cut");
    }

    //An item has been copied/cut
    if(storedItem)
    {
        menu.addAction("Paste");
    }

    QAction* action = menu.exec(evt->screenPos());
    if(action != 0x00)
    {
        if(action->text() == "Copy")
        {
            if(storedItem)
                delete storedItem;
            storedItem = createCopy(item); //has to be implemented
        }
        else if(action->text() == "Cut")
        {
            if(storedItem)
                delete storedItem;
            storedItem = item;
            removeItem(item);
        }
        else if(action->text() == "Paste")
        {
            QGraphicsItem* item = createCopy(storedItem);
            if(item) {
                addItem(item);
                item->setPos(evt->scenePos());
            }
        }
    }
}

QGraphicsItem* CadGraphicsScene::createCopy(QGraphicsItem* item)
{
    if(item == 0x00)
        return 0x00;

    if(item->type() == Circle::Type) //QGraphicsRectItem
    {
        Circle* copy = new Circle(-1, center_p, end_p);


        return copy;
    }

    return 0x00;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to connect a slot to the customContextMenuRequested-signal of the view, be aware has to be activated:

```
view->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu)
```

there you can get the current position of the cursor within the scene. When there is an item at that position, use a QMenu to either copy/cut the item, store it (or at least the information that you need)... and if there's no item you can paste it (means either reusing the previously cut item or creating a new one with the stored information).

Other ways are for example creating a custom graphics-item and overwrite the contextMenuEvent or handling the mousePressEvent...

Example using your defined "CadGraphicsScene" overwriting to "contextMenuEvent"-Function:

```
void CadGraphicsScene::contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent* evt)
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> itemsAt = items(evt->scenePos());

    QGraphicsItem* item = itemsAt.isEmpty() ? 0x00 : itemsAt.first();

    static QGraphicsItem* storedItem = 0x00;

    QMenu menu;

    //Item found
    if(item)
    {
        menu.addAction("Copy");
        menu.addAction("Cut");
    }

    //An item has been copied/cut
    if(storedItem)
    {
        menu.addAction("Paste");
    }

    QAction* action = menu.exec(evt->screenPos());
    if(action != 0x00)
    {
        if(action->text() == "Copy")
        {
            if(storedItem)
                delete storedItem;
            storedItem = createCopy(item); //has to be implemented
        }
        else if(action->text() == "Cut")
        {
            if(storedItem)
                delete storedItem;
            storedItem = item;
            removeItem(item);
        }
        else if(action->text() == "Paste")
        {
            QGraphicsItem* item = createCopy(storedItem);
            if(item) {
                addItem(item);
                item->setPos(evt->scenePos());
            }
        }
    }
}

QGraphicsItem* CadGraphicsScene::createCopy(QGraphicsItem* item)
{
    if(item == 0x00)
        return 0x00;

    if(item->type() == QGraphicsRectItem::Type) //QGraphicsRectItem
    {           
        QGraphicsRectItem* rectItem = (QGraphicsRectItem*)item;
        QGraphicsRectItem* copy = new QGraphicsRectItem(item->parentItem());
        copy->setRect(rectItem->rect());
        copy->setPen(rectItem->pen());
        copy->setBrush(rectItem->brush());
        return copy;
    }

    return 0x00;
}
```

The copy function in this case handles only QGraphicsRectItem, has to be extended for all necessary types.

Tested usign Qt 4.8...

Example of copy Circle:

```
Circle* copy = new Circle(-1, center_p, end_p); //Dont know where you get your ID
```

and then add the "copy"-object to the scene.

Comment: Can you please explain me with the help of small working example that how to use QMenu to copy/cut the item.

Comment: Example added: I'm not at my computer, so I was not able to run the code, but the code could look like above... However, there are many possible improvements to the above example, like for example creating the QMenu within the class and reusing it every time (only update the visibility of the actions each time the contextmenu is called)...

Comment: Did you try my example? @user3859872

Comment: I tried this but got lot of errors at text(), action and other places also. Can you please test the code once. I will also edit my question and will add cadgraphicsscene class to it.

Comment: Using the above code I am getting following two errors:1) error: void value not ignored as it ought to be "storedItem = createCopy(item);" 2)error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
"QGraphicsItem* item = createCopy(storedItem);"
                                                                ^

Comment: What system, qt version, etc. do you use?

Comment: System: Ubuntu 14.04 Qt version :5.2.1

Comment: Try to write your own copyItem method as it looks like something is going wrong with mine... Nevertheless, the error has to be on your side since I've tested my example and its working fine

Comment: I need some further information... What is not working (ok copy/paste but what exactly), where do you have problems?

Comment: The context menu is opening in the correct way, after the cut is done, paste option appears but nothing gets pasted, similarly create copy function is not working properly as the code needs to be adjusted according to my entity classes, I am not getting on how to adjust that code. I have posted one my entity class too. Please have a look and help/

Comment: I added above code in cadgraphicscsecne.cpp in createcopy function but got following error:  error: 'center_p' was not declared in this scope. Updated the code.

Comment: A bit of thinking is necessary though, where do you think did I get those values from? If you really don't get whats wrong there, I think you should start some simpler programming examples, learning principles, understanding whats going on, etc....

Comment: Hey I have tried the things using this approach, but it pastes just a point.

Comment: This is what I did:
Circle *copy = new Circle;
copy->centerP;
copy->endP;
copy->radius;

Comment: Can you paste the code where you copy your elements? Add it to your answer to get proper formatting